# Rendering WYSWYG edited text

Tags: html, tinymce, rendering

I am using TinyMce wysiwyg text editor. I could send the text as expected to the server. What unexpected is, webrowser is not rendering it very well.
text that is saved in the server is like this:

```
"&lt;p&gt;this is my content&lt;/p&gt;"
```

OKAY!
When I render it,

```
<p>this is my content</p>
```

is seen in the browser.
I am sure there is very minor thing behind it which I don't know right now. I save the content in MySql database and do simple ajax call to render the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode `&lt;p&gt;this is my content&lt;/p&gt;` at server side, it prevents malicious attacks code from your website

Comment: I didn't guessed that there must have reverse operation of encoding(htmlentities()).
Thanks @Joan